# Dependencies problem with automake

Tags: linux, c, dependencies, automake

I am using automake on Debian Squeeze for compiling a very simple C project with 6 source files.

The issue comes when I try to compile the sources using the generated Makefile. One of the sources (ll_socket.c) uses system libraries like  and . Those dependencies should appear in the ".deps/ll_socket.Tpo" file automatically generated; however, that file is empty and, therefore, when GCC tries to compile that file, it cannot find the dependencies for the compilation.

Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `automake -a` will take care of everything about dependencies while compiling a program. I have gone through this [document 1](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Dependencies.html) & [2](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Dependency-Tracking.html#Dependency-Tracking)  which explains about automake dependencies. I suggest you read that document for more information regards.

Comment: Let me explain the problem more 'in depth': the program is written in C and is composed of 6 source/headers files: main.c, main.h, configuration.c, configuration.h, ll_socket.c, ll_socket.h. For the "configuration.c", it generates a correct .po file under the ".deps" directory, since it contains a list with all the dependencies that the "configuration.c" file has. However, for the "ll_socket.c" the .po file under the ".deps" directory only contains the "# dummy" line so, when it comes to compile with GCC, dependencies cannot be satisfied.